# z3 with LIA logic can return real?

Tags: z3, solver, smt, z3py

I am experimenting with z3. I am surprised that, when setting the logic to LIA, z3 can return real numbers. For example, the following:

```
from z3 import *


sol = SolverFor("LIA") 

vB = Real('vB')

sol.add(vB < 3)
sol.add(vB > 2)


sol.check()
print(sol.model())
```

returns:

```
[vB = 5/2]
```

Can someone please explain how it can be the case?

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, this is a "bug" in z3. Here's the equivalent SMT script:

```
(set-logic LIA)
(declare-fun vB () Real)
(assert (< vB 3.0))
(assert (> vB 2.0))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

If you run this with cvc4/cvc5, you get:

```
(error "Parse Error: a.smt2:2.23: Symbol 'Real' not declared as a type

  (declare-fun vB () Real)
                     ^
")
```

And Yices says:

```
(error "at line 2, column 20: undefined sort: Real")
```

CVC and Yices are correct here, since you restricted the logic to "LIA", the name "Real" is no longer defined. Z3, however, is playing loose here, and allowing reals by default. (It internally uses logics to pick which algorithms to run, but it's not always consistent in making sure the logic restricts the names available.)

You can report this at the z3 issue tracker here: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues. I suspect they're already aware of this, but would be good to have it recorded.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation! Do you know which logic it uses to solve this problem then?

Comment: Logic selection restricts what names are available; doesn't really have anything to do with "solving." Solving is about algorithms and tactics. For this problem, it most likely uses the standard SMT tactic as it's pretty simple.

Comment: Oh interesting, does it mean that logic selection should not improve solving efficiency? (as long as the logic supports the problem)

Comment: If you specify a logic, you're essentially saying "this problem needs no features other than what's allowed by this logic." Thus, the solver can pick a more effective algorithm, knowing it's a "simpler" problem. For instance "LIA" means linear-integer arithmetic, so it does *not* need to bring in any machinery that requires non-linear reasoning (which is much harder). So, logic selection can restrict which algorithms are used, though of course the solver can itself notice that it doesn't need non-linearity even if you didn't say LIA. Think of the logic selection as a "hint" to the solver.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! I have one more question: my problem both uses int and real, it seems to belong to QF-LIRA (from 'Probe'). As per my understanding, QF-LIRA is not a logic available in z3, and both QF-LIA and QF-LRA are subsets of it. Would you recommend a particular logic in this case?

Comment: Unless you have a logic that matches one of the listed ones exactly, I'd recommend not setting it at all and let z3's default engine run. See here for the full list: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/21e59f7c6e5033006265fc6bc16e2c9f023db0e8/src/solver/check_logic.cpp#L70-L216

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is there a way to define a custom logic? Such as allowing m_ints and m_reals but disabling other features?

Comment: The logic list is fixed, see here: https://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/logics.shtml. In the past, there have been proposals to make the logic more customizable (i.e., pick-and-choose of individual features like you're suggesting), but the SMTLib committee didn't make that part of the standard yet. Maybe in the future. If you're interested, you can a message at https://groups.google.com/g/smt-lib to recreate the discussion. (I'd encourage you to do so; the committee is interested in hearing what end-users need/want.)